# prepare a set of arguments that can pass to a function in java

Tags: java, function, syntax

I want to call a function like `private void passStrings(String... arg){}`
And I have an array which store a set of Strings but don't know its size.
So How can I use all that array value and call the function passString().

Comment: use a while loop

Comment: @OLIVER.KOO: I think you may have missed the point of the question.

Comment: I thought the OP wants to call `passStrings()` for each `String` in his array, and that is why OP doesn't know how many time he should call `passStrings()` cause he doesn't know the array size? I could be wrong. (also @JonSkeet nice to meet you. I had to buy your book your book C# in depth two years ago when I was in college.)

Comment: @OLIVER.KOO: Given that `passStrings` *accepts* an array, I believe they can just call it once. I believe they just weren't aware that they *could* pass an array.

Comment: @JonSkeet It works fine. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass it *as* the array:

```
String[] array = { "Some", "arguments", "I", "prepared", "earlier" };
passStrings(array);
```

A varargs parameter like `arg` is still an array parameter really - it's just that the compiler *allows* you to specify the elements individually, if you want. It doesn't force you to though - if you've already got the array, just pass it.